# Blogger Dynamic View header drawer

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I find the header drawer just doesn't show right on my blogger

Do any one knows what's wrong? How can I fix it?

Here's my blog: http://iotxshon.blogspot.com/2013/08/bug.html

Comment: header drawer means what??

Answer (score 0):

It is a known blogger bug

Go to Dashboard, select Template from the pulldown menu, and Edit HTML. Then scroll down until you see the following lines at the bottom of the template:

```
 <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
      setTimeout(function() {
        blogger.ui().configure().view();
      }, 0);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Change the timeout value from 0 to 1000:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
      setTimeout(function() {
        blogger.ui().configure().view();
      }, 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Credit for this trick](http://www.2globalnomads.info/2013/06/blogger-dynamic-views-css-fail-bug-custom-reload.html)